# upload million rows in postgresql (nodejs) hosted in GCP

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, upload, insertion

We are trying to create an app in GCP using postgresql as backend and nodejs/angular for application side . As part of our requirement we need to be able to upload files of around 1 million records atleast in the development environment .

We werent able to pass threshold of 20k records initially howver after updating the value of POSTGRES_POOL_ACQUIRE env variable to 30000 and then to eventually 2million we are now able to upload 90 to 95k records.Not exactly sure how that helps but it has atleast allowed us to increase our threshold failure. However increase the value of the env variable post that (2million) doesnt provide any additional benefit.

We have also increased the timeout to 10 mins

```
POSTGRES_DB=XXXX
POSTGRES_USER=XXXXX
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XXXXX
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=XXXX
POSTGRES_DIALECT=postgres
POSTGRES_POOL_MAX=5
POSTGRES_POOL_MIN=0
POSTGRES_POOL_ACQUIRE=30000
POSTGRES_POOL_IDLE=10000
POSTGRES_OPERATOR_ALIASES=false
BCRYPT_NB = 5
```

What possible steps can we take further to be able to hit our upload target of 1 million records ? Do let us know if any additional information is required

Comment: What does POSTGRES_POOL_ACQUIRE do? And why would you increase this when you have more record to insert? (not a nodejs programmer myself)

Comment: honestly even i am not sure, but it seems to be some sort of env variables in node which allows some additional data from postgres. Surprisingly here is very little documentation about it

Comment: `acquire: maximum time, in milliseconds, that pool will try to get connection before throwing error` That is a rather strange variable to me. Why would you have to wait longer to get a connection, when you have more records to proces? Your pool-size maximum is 5, so you should have no more than 5 concurrent processes running. When a proces (or thread) is ready, it can start a new one. There is no reason to wait. Could you share the rest (or at least the relevant part) of your code?